# wysihtml5 bootstrap3-wysiwyg font size and <p> to <br>

Tags: wysihtml5, bootstrap-wysihtml5

I use [bootstrap3-wysiwyg](https://github.com/bootstrap-wysiwyg/bootstrap3-wysiwyg) based on [wysihtml5](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5)

I seek solution for

1. On "Enter" key insert "br" not  "p"
2. Button for change font size with input value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use 'br'

```js
$("#TextContent").wysihtml5({useLineBreaks: true, ...})
```

2. Font-size

```js
  var myCustomTemplates = {

    custom1: function (context) {
        var s = ""
        s += '<li class="dropdown">';
        s += '<a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="-1" aria-expanded="false">';
        s += '<span class="current-color">Size</span>';
        s += '<b class="caret"></b>';
        s += '</a>';
        s += '<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="margin-top: 0px;">';
        s += '<li><a class="fontSize" data-wysihtml5-command="fontSize" data-wysihtml5-command-value="fs5">5px</a></li>';
        s += '</ul>';
        s += '</li>';

        return s;
    }
};
```

```js
 $("#TextContent").wysihtml5(
        {
            customTemplates: myCustomTemplates,
            "stylesheets": ["~/Content/wysiwyg/editor.css"]
        });
```

editor.css

```css
.wysiwyg-font-size-fs5 {
    font-size: 5px;
}
```